# Cannot checkout GitLab repo fron Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, openshift

I am experiencing a strange issue. I am attempting to construct a Pipeline in Jenkins that will checkout code from a private GitLab repo and eventually deploy to our Openshift cluster. I went through all the [steps](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html#grant-jenkins-access-to-gitlab-project) here (grant permissions, generate access token and configure the GitLab project), set up the Gitlab connection in Manage Jenkins -> System -> GitLab (test connection was successful).

I then set up a simple multibranch pipeline, added a branch source (https://GITLAB_USER:ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab.com/REPO.git), for credentials I added the API token and then for pipeline script:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                echo 'Checkout'
                checkout scm
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It was then able to successfully connect to the repo and scan all the branches, but the build on master failed with:

```
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
and 
stderr: fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://GITLAB_USER@gitlab.com/REPO.git/'`
```

Any ideas on what is going on?